# remove end of line characters with a bash script?

Tags: linux, macos, bash, scripting, eof

I'm trying to make a script to remove this characters (/r/n) that windows puts. BUT ONLY if they are between this ( " ) why this?
because the dump file puts this characters I don't know why.
and why between quotes? because it only affect me if they are chopping my result

```
For Example. "this","is","a","result","from","database"
```

the problem :

```
"this","is","a","result","from","da
tabase"
```

[EDIT]

Thanks to the answer of @Cyrus I got something like this [image]

, but it gets bad flag in substitute command '}' I'm on MAC OSX

Can you help me?

Thanks

Comment: You mean end of *line* characters? And those are, on POSIX systems like Linux, only a single `'\n'`.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg yes please, I know what the characters are, but I don't know how to remove them,- for context - when I'm trying to export to Oracle the progress dump file, it has a conflict with eol characters that are chopping my result, thats why I want to remove them. thanks for the correction (Y)

Comment: Mac OSX? Please fix your tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OS X uses a different `sed` than the one that's typically installed in Linux.

The big differences are that sequences like `\r` and `\n` don't get expanded or used as part of the expression as you might expect, and you tend to need to separate commands with semicolons a little more.

If you can get by with a sed one-liner that implements a rule like "Remove any `\r\n` on lines containing quotes", it will certainly simplify your task...

For my experiments, I used what I infer is your sample input data:

```
$ od -c input.txt
0000000    F   o   r       E   x   a   m   p   l   e   .       "   t   h
0000020    i   s   "   ,   "   i   s   "   ,   "   a   "   ,   "   r   e
0000040    s   u   l   t   "   ,   "   f   r   o   m   "   ,   "   d   a
0000060    t   a  \r  \n   b   a   s   e   "  \n                        
0000072
```

First off, a shell-only solution might be to use smaller tools that are built in to the operating system.  For example, here's a one-liner:

```
od -A n -t o1 -v input.txt | rs 0 1 | while read n; do [ $n -eq 015 ] && read n && continue; printf "\\$n"; done
```

Broken out for easier reading, here's what this looks like:

- `od -A n -t o1 -v input.txt | rs 0 1` - convert the file into a stream of ocal numbers
- `| while read n; do` - step through the numbers...

  - `[ $n -eq 015 ] &&` - if the current number is 15 (i.e. octal for a Carriage Return)
  - `read n` - read a line (thus skipping it),
  - `&& continue` - and continue to the next octal number (thus skipping the newline after a CR)
  - `printf "\\$n"; done` - print the current octal number.

This kind of data conversion and stream logic works nicely in a pipeline, but is a bit harder to implement in sed, which only knows how to deal with the original input rather than its converted form.

Another bash option might be to use conditional expressions matching the original lines of input:

```
while read line; do
  if [[ $line =~ .*\".*$'\r'$ ]]; then
    echo -n "${line:0:$((${#line}-1))}"
  else
    echo "$line"
  fi
done < input.txt
```

This walks through text, and if it sees a CR, it prints everything up to and not including it, with no trailing newline.  For all other lines, it just prints them as usual.  The result is that lines that had a carriage return are joined, other lines are not.

From sed's perspective, we're dealing with two input lines, the first of which ends in a carriage return.  The strategy for this would be to search for carriage returns, remove them and join the lines.  I struggled for a while trying to come up with something that would do this, then gave up.  Not to say it's impossible, but I suspect a generally useful script will be lengthy (by sed standards).

Comment: AMAZING !!! And very well explained! I learned a lot from this, thank you very much ghoti

Comment: How would you just delete the Carriage Return? I mean I did what u said and put it like >> newtext.txt and it worked like a charm, but the real file it's about 10Gb, and doing `>> newtext.txt`will be terrible I suppose and your first 1 liner example you printed it, can you help me removing the CR from the file?

Comment: @jompi, in the first option, data moves through a pipe. In the second, we're using input redirection. So neither method should have any problem with a 10GB (or any size) file.  Pipes and redirection are nice in that they don't have to "load a file into memory" to process it, they only handle the *stream* (or a small buffer of it).